# Bluetooth pairing between android phone and windows 10 surface book

Tags: windows-10, android, bluetooth

I don't succeed in transferring files between phone and computer (which is sometimes not comfortable, for example when you prepare a trip on your computer and need to quickly transfer any confirmation document to your phone, because, as an absent-minded like me, you think about it when you are just about to leave).

I tried to do bluetooth pairing exactly as it is indicated in >> [this link](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-connect-android-device-windows-10-pc-using-bluetooth) <<. And, indeed, in the end, my phone appeared as "connected" in the windows 10 bluetooth panel. *But*, I was not able to browse my phone files from computer nor my computer files from phone.

And two seconds later, the bluetooth status of my phone on my computer changed from "connected" to "paired" again.

I tried to restart, reinstall drivers, switch off and on again bluetooth on both apparatus, de-pair and re-pair, but none of these options work, so I'm coming here for a solution.

My computer is a Windows Surface Book (Windows 10 64 bits i7 16GB RAM 1TB memory) and my phone is an Android (LG-P760).

Thanks in advance for your help .

Answer (score 0):

You have researched well and, unfortunately, there seems to be no panacea to this problem. Bluetooth is simply finicky.

Instead, you can use Surface Book's Wi-Fi adapter for file transfer. (You don't need a Wi-Fi hotspot.) There is the bonus of speed for this too. [Zapya](http://www.izapya.com/) and [SHAREit](http://www.ushareit.com/) are two of the apps that you can use to quickly transfer files between a computer and mobile device over Wi-Fi. Try them. You'll have to install these apps both on the phone and the PC.

Comment: Thanks. However, where I am there is no Wi Fi, only an ethernet connection. Does this work with 3G?

Comment: You have a Surface Book! It has a Wi-Fi adapter in it! You don't need a Wi-Fi hotspot. Surface Book transmits directly to your phone. And vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Xender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.xender&hl=en).

It has better option for sharing files between phone and computer by wifi.

1. On Android, in Xender choose "PC connect" option
2. On PC browser, type http://192.168.43.1:33455/web/index.html